# Select unique combination of entities from different lists using keys

Tags: python

Apologies if this question has been asked, I may not have the necessary vocabulary to find the correct question.

If I have some equal-length lists (or tuples) of things like this:

```
[6, 4, 7] [gold, blue, red] [dog, cat, echidna] [hot, cold, rainy]
```

And a set of keys that are consecutive integers in a known range that is equal to the number of unique combinations (in this case 81).

Is is possible to select one item from each list for each key, such that the combination is guaranteed to be unique? (and also get the key from the combination).

so that

0 might yield (6, gold, cat, hot)

1 might yield (cat, 4, gold, rainy)

2 might yield (hot, red, echidna, 7)

etc...

And know that (hot, red, echidna, 7) is the selection produced by 2?

Assuming the length and order of the lists is known and fixed, the items in the lists are guaranteed to be unique within each list and across all lists, and each list can be ordered/sorted

Comment: Are the keys guaranteed to be consecutive integers?  If not, are they all at least less than the number of available selections?  Please note that your given example doesn't quite work: you posit 100 keys, but there are only 81 distinct results to generate: 4 lists of 3 items each => 3^4 possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: 50 doesn't help.  You need exactly 81 for this specific problem in order to have a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question again.

Comment: What assumptions can be made about the lists' contents?  Are the items guaranteed to be unique (at least within each list)?  Are they sortable / comparable to each other (again, within a single list)?

Comment: Will the input lists always be the same length as each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an effective mapping without materializing a data structure by using a formula.  Say we repeatedly take n mod the length of each sequence and divide by the lengths.  That gives us:

```
def get_nth(seqs, n):
    out = []
    for seq in seqs:
        i = n % len(seq)
        n //= len(seq)
        out.append(seq[i])
    return out
```

after which we have

```
>>> seqs = [[6, 4, 7], ['gold', 'blue', 'red'],
        ['dog', 'cat', 'echidna'], ['hot', 'cold', 'rainy']]
>>> get_nth(seqs, 0)
[6, 'gold', 'dog', 'hot']
>>> get_nth(seqs, 1)
[4, 'gold', 'dog', 'hot']
>>> get_nth(seqs, 80)
[7, 'red', 'echidna', 'rainy']
>>> len(set(tuple(get_nth(seqs, i)) for i in range(81)))
81
```

This will work very quickly even on long lists:

```
>>> seqs = [list(range(10**3))]*10**3
>>> %timeit get_nth(seqs, 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 592 µs per loop
>>> %timeit get_nth(seqs, (10**3)**(10**3)-1)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop
>>> get_nth(seqs, (10**3)**(10**3)-1)[:10]
[999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999]
```

Answer (score 1):

## All Elements in All Lists are Unique

If the input values are all unique in different list then you can just. Reduced the elements for less output

```
import itertools

input = [[6, 4], ['gold', 'blue'], ['dog', 'cat'], ['hot', 'cold']];
output = list(itertools.product(*input))
print output
```

So `list[0] -> (6, 'gold', 'dog', 'hot')`

**Output**

```
 [(6, 'gold', 'dog', 'hot'), (6, 'gold', 'dog', 'cold'), (6, 'gold', 'cat', 'hot'), (6, 'gold', 'cat', 'cold'), 
 (6, 'blue', 'dog', 'hot'), (6, 'blue', 'dog', 'cold'), (6, 'blue', 'cat', 'hot'), (6, 'blue', 'cat', 'cold'), 
 (4, 'gold', 'dog', 'hot'), (4, 'gold', 'dog', 'cold'), (4, 'gold', 'cat', 'hot'), (4, 'gold', 'cat', 'cold'), 
 (4, 'blue', 'dog', 'hot'), (4, 'blue', 'dog', 'cold'), (4, 'blue', 'cat', 'hot'), (4, 'blue', 'cat', 'cold')]
```

## Not all elements in all lists are unique

Then just use itertools.groupby

```
import itertools

input = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]];
output = [k for k,_ in list(itertools.groupby(itertools.product(*input)))]
print output
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2], 
[1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

## Performance

With your example timeit with number=1000

```
0.00650215148926 (without group by)
0.02952003479    (with group by)
0.0323181152344  (algorithm from @GarrettR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.  Thought it doesn't supposed that you have a list of keys.  Instead it generates keys on the fly by enumerating the product of your lists.

```
a,b,c,d = [6, 4, 7], ['gold', 'blue', 'red'], ['dog', 'cat', 'echidna'], ['hot', 'cold', 'rainy']
from itertools import product
forward = {}
backward = {}
for i,thing in enumerate(product(a,b,c,d)):
    forward[i] = thing
    backward[thing] = i
```

## Example Mappings Forward

```
77 -> (7, 'red', 'cat', 'rainy')
78 -> (7, 'red', 'echidna', 'hot')
79 -> (7, 'red', 'echidna', 'cold')
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This works well for the example in the question but I wonder if there is a faster way. In the wild I have a little over 3000 items in each list so this is going to be rather slow.

Comment: Have you tried it? `product` returns a generator expression so it doesn't build the whole list of tuples all at once.

Comment: With 3 lists of 3088 items it took 0.01s to get to the millionth key, 1s for the 10 millionth and 9s for the 100 millionth. Not bad considering what is going on.

Comment: did you need it to be faster than that?

Comment: Ideally yes, there are so many possible combinations that I cannot pre-calculate and store these combinations.

Comment: @alex my answer with itertools should be 5 to 10% faster.